# Variables in A Function

Tags: php

So, basically, my function will display an error if i replace $check_string in the if statement with $string.

Why is this? I thought a function parameter was just something you pass arguments through.

```
<?

$string = 'Kwame Tenkorang Darko';

function checkforspace($check_string){

if(preg_match('/ /', $check_string)){

    return true;
}

else{

    return false;
}

}



if(checkforspace($string)){
echo 'one space';
}

else {
echo 'no space';
}

?>
```

Comment: There are two `if` statements in your code.  Which one?  And what error?

Comment: if(preg_match('/ /', $check_string))     this the one im talking about

Comment: That's inside your function, so the "scope" answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to scope of that variable. 
You can learn the scope of variables by going through this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

> In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function. - [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
$string = 'Kwame Tenkorang Darko';
//  ^ 
// global variable

function checkforspace () {
    global $string;
    //         ^
    // 'Kwame Tenkorang Darko'

    return preg_match('/\s/', $string);
    // ^
    // same logic as your function, just refactored
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?PHP
function checkforspace($string){
     return (strpos($string," ") != -1);// if exist " " return the position else return -1
}
?>
```